# Holes in 3D cuboid

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to (well, more-or-less) recreate this drawing in TikZ:

[image]

It is quite easy to draw this grey plate, the surface and the arrows, but I have absolutely no idea how can I reproduce these holes and lines passing through them properly.

Could somebody direct me in the right way?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fake hole sticker that you can paste on any surface,

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikz{
    \draw(.7,.5)ellipse[x radius=.7,y radius=.3];
    \clip(1.4,1)--(1.4,0)arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,x radius=.7,y radius=.3]--(0,1);
    \clip(.7,.5)ellipse[x radius=.7,y radius=.3];
    \shade[left color=black,right color=black,middle color=white](-1,0)rectangle(2,1);
    \draw(1.4,0)arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,x radius=.7,y radius=.3];
    \draw(.7,.5)ellipse[x radius=.7,y radius=.3];
}

\end{document}
```

[image]